# CSRF token issues with Express

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, csrf

I am trying to get CSRF protection working using `csurf` and `express`. My app uses Angular for the front end, so I figured adding this to my app would be enough:

```
app.use(cookieParser('test secret'));
app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: 'test secret'
}));
app.use(csrf({
    cookie: {
        key: 'XSRF-TOKEN'
    }
}));
```

However, when I try to make POST requests, I get 403 ("invalid CSRF token") errors.
As far as I can tell, the issue resides in the `csrf-tokens` module: at line 44, the `expected` variable looks like `qMnHLQGhivxECx5WtwuktDNA-snimacq30z-XNh2X-KTpdlkU6Og` while the `secret` and `token` variables look like `qMnHLQGhivxECx5WtwuktDNA`. Since `expected` and `token` are different, a 403 error occurs.

I have, so far, tried the following:

- Setting `secure: false` and/or `signed: true` in my `csurf` options
- Making sure that my `cookie-session` and `cookie-parser` middleware run before `csurf`
- Re-installing all my `npm` modules just in case
- Yelling at my computer

I could, potentially, switch to session-based tokens, but that wouldn't work as smoothly with Angular, and I'm not sure if it would even solve my problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue, or what the cause might be?

**P.S.** By the way, I've also noticed a (probably unrelated) issue: the `req.csrfToken()` method seems to return strings whose values are entirely unrelated to the `expected` value in `csrf-tokens` or to the string being stored in the cookie.

Comment: which version of connect are you using ? This could help too http://www.mircozeiss.com/using-csrf-with-express-and-angular/

Comment: I'm using Express 4.2.0, so I'm not using Connect at all.

Comment: I am running into a similar, if not the same issue. Was there every any resolution here?

Comment: Honestly I don't see any apparent problem in what u are doing. May be give this a try https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-csrf-cross-domain/blob/master/dist/angular-csrf-cross-domain.js

Answer (score 8):

There is an error/bad implementation regarding csurf lib. The cookie "XSRF-TOKEN" does not store the csrf Token, but the secret that csurf uses to generate the csrf token. Therefore, the Angular part of your app identifies the XSRF-TOKEN and appends the header correctly to HTTP requests, but the csurf middleware does not recognize the secret as a valid CSRF token itself. To fix this problem, you should implement this as:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
app.use(cookieParser("secret"));
app.use(cookieSession({secret: "secret2"}));
app.use(csrf());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN",req.csrfToken());
    return next();
});
```

The req.csrfToken() will generate the csrf token based on the secret stored, in this case, in the req.session.csrfSecret variable, generated by the csrf middleware. Then, it will work.

**EDIT:** See this issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/issues/14)